# admin_consent_scope & prod vs dev separation

Tags: docusignapi

I almost finished an end-to-end integration with DocuSign within our web application.
Here are the high level features:

1 - We allow a user to connect his DocuSign account in our user settings using the JWT Authorization Flow.

- We craft the consent url if user never connected (state in our
  database).
- The user consent and then we create the JWT token using his 'sub'
  user guid value and obtain an access token.

2 - The user can create a signature request (from file or template) for clients in our app (not having a DocuSign account)

- We use the previously obtained access token from JWT
- We create the envelope, add recipients and set their clientUserId
  prop from our database

3 - Clients see the signature request in our app and click to sign the document(s).

- The signature object is stored in our db with the envelope_id and an
  association to the envelope's sender access token data so we can
  retrieve the original access token to call the create recipient view
  API
- Using this token, we get the DocuSign signature view url

4 - After the envelope creation, all the signature states are driven by the Connect(Webhook) that matches events with the envelope_id and recipients clientUserId to update our database and send notifications.

**Questions:**

1. About Step 1 above, I have read the documentation and it seems I can
   pass an extra 'admin_consent_scope' attribute. I am not using it
   right now and I can obtain a valid token, should I use it ?
2. How should we approach the dev/qa/stg/prod isolation ? Should I
   create a complete separate DocuSign account for each ? I can create
   different apps/integration keys in a single account but the Connect
   endpoints does not seem to be linkable to those apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To obtain admin consent you need to [set up an organization](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=rrf1583359212854&topicId=tif1583359135245.html&_LANG=enus)
2. Then you can [obtain administrative consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/) for the entire organization. It is done separately in production from the developer account.
3. For dev and prod you have everything separate except the IK (Integration Key) which is promoted to prod after you [go live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/). But you have to have separate accounts, consent, keys and any other configuration element in production.

Comment: Thank you Inbar, here are follow up questions: 1 - Our use case is really a public web application targeted at individual users or companies, in that case I don't see the administrative consent would be the ideal scenario. I just want to let a person connect their account to our app in the most frictionless possible way. For 3 - I understand that I need to signup in different DocuSign accounts to isolate everything. Thank you

Comment: In that case, you may want to ask every customer to use a dedicated "system user" and set it up once with consent for your app. You can create a configuration screen in your app that allows the administrator to log-in with their system user, obtain consent, and store the userId in your system so that you can always use it to obtain an access token using JWT. This step will have to be done once by every customer (meaning they have a    different account) in order to use your app.

Comment: Got it, but given that we have a concept of team, this could be done by the admin only once. Thanks this is exactly how I implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

> About Step 1 above, I have read the documentation and it seems I can pass an extra 'admin_consent_scope' attribute. I am not using it right now and I can obtain a valid token, should I use it ?

I recommend that you implement a smooth individual consent flow (it sounds like you did) rather then using Admin Consent:

In order for an ISV's application to use Admin Consent, your customer needs:

1. Organization feature, and set up an org (join accounts to the org)
2. Claim the DNS email domain used in the email addresses of the org users
3. Implement the Admin Consent flow in your ISV application

Note that if there are users who have a different email address root domain (eg @bigcompany.com plus @bigcompanyfinance.com) then either the additional domain needs to be claimed (more than one can be claimed) or those users must use individual consent.

#### Bottom line on Admin Consent

- Most customers don't have Orgs
- You don't want to require your customers to implement all of the above in order to use your application's integration with DocuSign.
- Recommended: implement a smooth individual consent flow if you're using JWT OAuth

> How should we approach the dev/qa/stg/prod isolation ? Should I create a complete separate DocuSign account for each ? I can create different apps/integration keys in a single account but the Connect endpoints does not seem to be linkable to those apps

I don't understand what you mean by "Connect endpoints does not seem to be linkable to those apps"

You can create separate demo accounts for your team's different roles.

Also, as Inbar noted, the demo version of your client ID (integration key) is completely different (different set of settings, etc) from the production version. Except, both the demo and production client IDs share the same guid.

Comment: Thank you Larry. What I meant by Connect endpoints... is that I could have created a DEV/QA/Prod integration keys but still I have no way to configure a specific  webhook endpoint. Like I cannot separate dev.myapi.com/webhook from prod.myapi.com, it seems that the Connect section in DocuSign is account wide. I understand that I just need to create a separated account for each env.

Comment: Correct. Webhooks are either defined per envelope or per account. They aren't associated with client IDs