# How to obtain the docusign user guid to set on the JWT sub attribute?

Tags: docusignapi

It seems that I am missing a piece in the JWT Consent Flow.

1. I craft the following consent url and link it to a button that will
   open a popup for the current user to login and accept the consent:
   [https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=#{my_integration_key}&redirect_uri=#{redirect_url}"](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=#%7Bmy_integration_key%7D&redirect_uri=#%7Bredirect_url%7D%22)
2. Once redirected, the documentation specifies that I should simply
   ignore the code param in the redirect url.
3. I must create a JWT token in order to obtain an access token : At
   this point I must specify the 'sub' with the user ID of the user who
   just granted consent. How I am suppose to get it in this flow? I
   don't understand why I should ignore the code param in the oauth
   redirect, I should use it to find the DocuSign user guid.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userId GUID can be obtained in many ways, but that depends on the flow of your app.

You could go to check it in the Settings (admin) portion of the web app, either in the "Apps and Keys" page, where you get the logged in user ID, or in the
"User" where you can find any and all users in the account.

However, if you want to do that programmatically, you are in a catch22, as to make an API call to obtain this information you need to first be authenticated. Typically, this can be done by hardcoding a primary user (system user) that was set manually and that user then make API call to obtain all other users and their GUID (userID) respectively.

Comment: Hi Inbar, my use case is the one reference in my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74707447/323329 but the flow of our app is to obtain consent from external user, we want them to connect their own docusign account so I cannot use the user id my developer account. Even if I hardcode my own user id I will only have access to my dev account, not the user who consented. At first I did implement the Code Authorization Flow where each user needs to auth login but I refactored to use the JWT flow because I needed to call the create recipient view api for non docusign users...

Comment: You can do it in two steps. First, use Auth Code Grant, to get the user logged in. You don't need to generate using JWT, you can use Auth Code Grant (if you can store a secret on your server). Once the user is logged in and you got an access code you will know their userID. Then you store that userID in your system, so the next time you can use JWT

Comment: One thing to remember if you do the above, add the "impersonation" scope when you do Auth Code Grant, so the consent will be used later for JWT without issues.

Comment: Ok, using the Authorization Code Grant before attempting to perform JWT Auth was the missing element for me, thank you